# Stackdriver custom multiline logging, time format

Tags: fluentd, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've been trying to set up a custom multiline log parser to get logs into Stackdriver with some readable fields. Currently it looks like this:

```
<source>
    type tail
    read_from_head true
    path /root/ansible.log
    pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/ansible.pos
    time_format "%a %b %e %T %Z %Y"
    format multiline
    format_firstline /Started ansible run at/
    format1 /Started ansible run at (?<timestart>[^\n]+)\n(?<body>.*)/
    format2 /PLAY RECAP.*/
    format3 /ok=(?<ok>\d+)\s+changed=(?<changed>\d+)\s+unreachable=(?<unreachable>\d+)\s+failed=(?<failed>\d+).*/
    format4 /Finished ansible run at (?<timeend>[^\n]+)/
    tag ansible
</source>
```

It's done to the specifications at http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/parser_multiline, and it works. But it works without a proper time stamp - `timestart` and `timeend` are just simple fields in the json. So in this current state, the `time_format` setting is useless, because I don't have a `time` variable among the regexes. This does aggregate all the variables I need, logs show up in Stackdriver when I run the fluend service, and all is almost happy.

However, when I change one of those time variables' name to `time`, trying to actually assign a Stackdriver timestamp to the entry, it doesn't work. The fluentd log on the machine says that the worker started and parsed everything, but logs don't show up in the Stackdriver console at all.

`timestart` and `timeend` look like `Fri Jun  2 20:39:58 UTC 2017` or something along those lines. The time format specifications are at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime and I've checked and double checked them too many times and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: another detail: when I try to parse out the `time` variable, while the logs don't show up in the Stackdriver console, the appropriate tag (in this case `ansible`) shows up in the list of tags. It's just that the results are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the Stackdriver logging agent looks for the timestamp in the `'time'` field, but it uses Ruby's [Time.iso8601](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-iso8601) to parse that value (falling back on [Time.at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-c-at) on error). The string you quoted (`Fri Jun  2 20:39:58 UTC 2017`) is not in either of those formats, so it fails to parse it (you could probably see the error in `/var/log/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.log`).
You could add a [record_transformer](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/filter_record_transformer) plugin to your config to change your parsed date to the right format (hint: `enable_ruby` is your friend). Something like:

```
<filter foo.bar>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    time ${Time.strptime(record['time'], '%a %b %d %T %Z %Y').iso8601}
  </record>
</filter>
```

should work...

Comment: Except, as I said, I don't see any errors in the fluentd log, the fluentd log says everything is ok, it's just that the logs don't show up in Stackdriver. And as for the time format, I'm already trying to use `%a %b %e %T %Z %Y` in the above block, so I'm just wondering why my method isn't working.